# Permission Error in Python program using vs code while running the program

Tags: python, html, windows, error-handling, runtime-error

`serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM17': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)`
I get this error when trying to show my data from sensor to website using flask python as html, and if i just show the data in terminal python it can run but if I add some code to show with html, i got the error. i just add code for put index.html on mypython thanks i hope i can solve later.....

i tried to install driver port and not solved, I'm sure I have good cable or components, and code is fine but I'm not understanding what permission the code needs, and my PC is windows BTW.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To give us a better idea of what's going on, it's helpful to include your actual code.   
This error sometimes occurs when another process is already using your port. Does your program spawn a child process that might continue after you close the program? Do you have Arduino IDE (or whatever software you use to interface with your device) open? Anything else that might be trying to communicate with your device?

Comment: to long for include my actual code of my program but iam sure no using the prot except my code, cause sometime i just open 1 apk.